# Tint a drawable pre Lollipop

Tags: java, android

So i'm trying to tint some Drawable at runtime, to achieve this i'm using a custom Resources class to return the Drawable tinted.

Something like:

```
public final class MyResources extends Resources
{
    public Drawable getDrawable(int resId) throws NotFoundException {
        Drawable drawable = super.getDrawable(resId);
        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

When the drawable is set to the widget, In some widgets like EditText, Buttons the drawable is mutated and the filter is lost.

The real code is at: https://github.com/SiegenthalerSolutions/QuantumPaper/blob/master/library/src/main/java/me/siegenthaler/quantum_paper/QuantumResources.java

And what i want is to prevent setting the drawable for the second time: (Hackish)

https://github.com/SiegenthalerSolutions/QuantumPaper/blob/master/library/src/main/java/me/siegenthaler/quantum_paper/interceptor/SimpleBackgroundInterceptor.java

Answer (score 0):

Try my library. I implemented a special drawable to tint drawables for custom EditText. This should work for all other cases too.

https://github.com/rekire/TintedDrawable